# Scope of the object should be not visible but its appear how that could happen?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

This is the HTML code of the section that Display our view model into table,

**Accounts** is the array of accounts :
Every **Account** have :

1 - Id
2- Name
3- Balance
4- Deposits

And There is Computed function called **Count** that count how many account in the accounts array

Accounts and Count in the same Scope which is the ViewModel object

```
 <table class="accounts-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Index   </td>
            <td>Id      </td>
            <td>Accounts</td>
            <td>Balance </td>
            <td>Deposits</td>
            <td>Counts</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data:Accounts, as: 'Account'}">
        <tr>
            <td class="accounts-table" data-bind="text:($index() + 1) + '/' + Count()" ></td>
            <td class="accounts-table" data-bind="text:Id"></td>
            <td class="accounts-table" data-bind="text:Name"></td>
            <td class="accounts-table" data-bind="text:Balance"></td>
            <td class="accounts-table">
                <ul data-bind="foreach: {data: Deposits, as: 'Amount'}">
                    <li data-bind="text:Account.Name + ' Deposits ' + Amount"></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

And this is the Javascript section :

```
 <script>
    function Account(id, name, balance, deposits) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Balance = balance;
        this.Deposits = deposits;
    }

    var myAccountViewModel = function () {
        this.Accounts = ko.observableArray([
            new Account(1, "A1", 1000, [100, 200, 300]),
            new Account(2, "A2", 2000, [400, 200, 900]),
            new Account(3, "A3", 3000, [600, 200, 800]),
            new Account(4, "A4", 4000, [700, 450, 300]),

        ]);
        this.Count = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.Accounts().length;
        },this);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(myAccountViewModel);
</script>
```

in This line :

```
 <td class="accounts-table" data-bind="text:($index() + 1) + '/' + Count()" ></td>
```

When I called Count function it works how this happen?
How the count function worked inside the Account Scope ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't instantiate a `new` viewmodel upon applying bindings.

This means that `myAccountViewModel` runs in the context of `window`, adding the `Count` property to `window`.

```js
function SomeConstructor() {
  console.log("this is window", this === window);
  this.someProp = "x";
};

// Call without `new`, and `this` refers to `window`
SomeConstructor();

// `someProp` is now in `window`:
console.log("window.someProp", window.someProp);

// Call it with `new` and everything's fine!
new SomeConstructor();
```

Because knockout uses `with` under the hood, eventually, data-binds will access `window` to resolve any undefined properties.

```js
window.someProp = "x";

var someBindingContext = {
  anotherProp: "y"
};

with (someBindingContext) {
  console.log(anotherProp); // Logs y
  console.log(someProp); // Logs x, even though `someProp` is in `window`
}
```

Change your apply bindings line to `ko.applyBindings(new myAccountViewModel())` to "fix" it. Now, you'll need `$parent.Count()` in your inner binding.

```js
function Account(id, name, balance, deposits) {
  this.Id = id;
  this.Name = name;
  this.Balance = balance;
  this.Deposits = deposits;
}

var myAccountViewModel = function() {
  this.Accounts = ko.observableArray([
    new Account(1, "A1", 1000, [100, 200, 300]),
    new Account(2, "A2", 2000, [400, 200, 900]),
    new Account(3, "A3", 3000, [600, 200, 800]),
    new Account(4, "A4", 4000, [700, 450, 300]),

  ]);
  this.Count = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.Accounts().length;
  }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new myAccountViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="accounts-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Index </td>
      <td>Id </td>
      <td>Accounts</td>
      <td>Balance </td>
      <td>Deposits</td>
      <td>Counts</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data:Accounts, as: 'Account'}">
    <tr>
      <td class="accounts-table" data-bind="text:($index() + 1) + '/' + $parent.Count()"></td>
      <td class="accounts-table" data-bind="text:Id"></td>
      <td class="accounts-table" data-bind="text:Name"></td>
      <td class="accounts-table" data-bind="text:Balance"></td>
      <td class="accounts-table">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: {data: Deposits, as: 'Amount'}">
          <li data-bind="text:Account.Name + ' Deposits ' + Amount"></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```